# Why does "Garfield" have so much product placement?

Tags: product-placement, garfield

Why does the 2004 film *Garfield* with Bill Murray have so much product placement? And why did Jon put "Pepsi" and "Wendy" Stickers on his Train Set?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Because they *can*....producers like having money thrown at them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe because Davis (the author of Garfield) wrote Garfield specifically to be "a good, marketable character." Before creating Garfield, Davis worked in advertising, and knew that if he could create a character he could sell, then it wouldn't really matter the content of the cartoon. [Slate has an excellent article about the marketing of Garfield.](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/assessment/2004/06/garfield.single.html)

So, knowing that Davis isn't against marketing, he'd probably not be against it. Knowing that movies cost money, putting advertising in movies is a good way to fund the movie (especially if you don't expect it to recoup production costs). [Hollywood Branded puts product placement for TV shows from $25k ~ $1m](https://blog.hollywoodbranded.com/how-much-does-product-placement-cost), but don't actually put a price on product placement in movies- but you can be guaranteed it's a significant amount.

As to *why* John would put those stickers on his train set, the out-of-universe answer is definitely because Pepsi and Wendy's spent money for product placement. For the in-universe answer, I have no idea. I think you'll have to find one of the 5 other people that watched the movie and ask them about it.

Comment: For the in-universe answer .... I had a train set as a kid, and it had fake 1930's advertising on it.  The world has advertising, so obsessive model makers will put advertising in their models.